# creating slug in wordpress while inserting data from csv

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a plugin to upload the csv to wordpress. what i want to know is how to create the slug of the title while inserting it into wp_posts.

Current i am using normal mysql query to insert the data.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `post_name` column in `wp_posts` contains the slug. For generating the slug itself use [`sanitize_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title)